# How do I change the numbers in the variable with the For Loop on Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop

I have a pandas dataframe like this :

```
id  target
0   0.5595
1   0.9642
2   0.6225
3   0.1256
4   0.1966
```

For example, if the numbers in the target variable are greater than 0.5, I want to add 0.2 and change that number.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here [no loops](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55557758/2901002) are necessary, because vectorized alternatives exist.

Using [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) is the simplest way:

```
df.loc[df.target.gt(0.5), 'target'] += 0.2
```

Which is the same as:

```
df.loc[df.target.gt(0.5), 'target'] = df.loc[df.target.gt(0.5), 'target'] + 0.2
```

It is also possible to use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df.target = np.where(df.target.gt(0.5), df.target + 0.2, df.target)
```

Btw, the not recommended `for` solution would be:

```
df.target = [x + 0.2 if x > 0.5 else x for x in df.target]
```